# Get selected text from drop-down list (select box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

This is my select code. I want to alert value of label: 'subalertTypeDesc'.
How can I do this using jquery/js?

```html
<select id="portfolioSubTypes" name="portfolioSubTypes" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect', validators: [genericSelectionValidator], 
                                                    value: portfolioSubTypesVal,disabled: allCustomersPlaceHolder() ? true : false, 
                                                    options: portfoliosubTypeLst, optionsKeys: {label: 'subalertTypeDesc', value: 'subalertTypeId'},
                                                    rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:20em'}}">
                        </select>
```

Comment: where is your select code? how is that linked to this label? When do you want to alert the value?

Comment: I'm posting here for the first time..so please try to be patient..

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

add the following code to your page

```
<script> 
    $("#portfolioSubTypes").change(function(){
       var txt =  $("#portfolioSubTypes option:selected").text();
       alert(txt);
    });

</script>
```